# Magento - Assign product to subcategory after indicization of parent

Tags: duplicate-content, links, magento

I have decided to create some subcategories to better separate the product, untill now(2 years) I only had the category with the brand name, but now I would like to add some subcategories:

- Brand

  - Face
  - Body

and Google shows this as snippet:

```
www.example.com › Home › Area › Brand
```

My question is: how should I act to avoid google errors like duplicated content or similar? Should I remove all the products associated to the category `Brand`, link them to the subcategories and anchor to the parent? or should I leave the actual configugration and add `noindex` to the subcategory?

Comment: Why are you worried about duplicate content?  Would putting products into a subcategory cause them to become available at an additional URL?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That is what I was thinking, but meanwhile I have read some articles, I have added the canonical URL and pointed it to the `"root"` `magento/product`, then removed all the asssociated product from the parent category and added them to the sub ones. What was worrying me was the fact that the products are available from `category/product` and `category/sub/product` , but if I haven't undesrtood wrong the `canonical url` solve this problem, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Using meta canonical tags to set the preferred URL would solve the problem, yes.  Feel free to answer your own question.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: add the canonical URL to the product page and point it to the "root" magento/product.
**Not sure if necessary, but probably yes for the sitemap**: remove all the asssociated product from the parent category and add them to the sub ones.